# Initiating value in 'if' and using it in the code error

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    System.out.println("\n What is the chemical symbol for water\n 1.HO2 \n 2.H20 \n 3.OOH \n 4. O2H");
    b = input.nextInt();
    if (b==2) {
        B=20;
    }
    else if (b != 2) {
        B=0;
    }

    **total= A+B;**
    switch (total) {    
        case 40:
            System.out.println("WOW You scored 40/40, you sure know your science");
            break;
        case 20:
            System.out.println("Meh,20/40.");
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("0/40 Better luck next time!");
            break;
    }
```

Im making a simple mcq practise app, that will grade its user according to the number of correct answers. i used if to give the integers 'A' and 'B' value according to answer. however it is giving me the error at **total=A+B** that **A** *(A has been initialized in an earlier if statement similar to this)* and **B** have not yet been initialized. any solutions? please excuse me im a nooby

Comment: Java and Javascript are very different languages. Are you actually interested in Javascript here? If not, edit your post to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize B before the if statement.

```
    B = 0;
    if (b==2)
        B=20;
    else if (!(b==2))
        B=0;
    total= A+B;
```

Of course, if you do that, you don't need the else part :

```
    B = 0;
    if (b==2)
        B=20;
    total= A+B;
```

Answer (score 5):

The Java compiler will not determine that at least one of the `if` and `else if` bodies will execute and that `B` will be initialized, so it thinks that if both conditions fail, then `B` won't be initialized.

You intended for the conditions to be opposites, so that exactly one condition will be `true`, so just use an `else`.  With an `else`, instead of an `else if`, the compiler will see that `B` will always be initialized by the time you use it later.

```
if (b==2)
    B=20;
else
    B=0;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there any examples of compilers that can detect logical opposites in if/elseif/else structures and handle it?